# Are these reaction mechanisms correct?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism

[image]

[image]

Are these reaction mechanisms correct for Ammonia and Bromide anions acting as a base respectively?

Comment: Can't say if its correct, but it sounds ok

Comment: I haven't seen the 'dative' arrow used as you have to show a bond between nitrogen and hydrogen (top right) or nitrogen and methyl (bottom right). A regular line without the lone pair on nitrogen is more conventional.

Comment: If you use dative bond arrows, which are a representation of an ionic lewis structure, the charge should be located at the hydrogen in the first reaction and at the carbon in the second reaction. In the second reaction, the product should not have a dative bond any more, as the molecule changed with the abstraction of the proton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the missing equilibrium arrow (these reaction are acid-base equilibria), they are fine. Or do you have any objections :) (what makes you doubt) ?

Also take @jerepierre's comment in account. This would probably be considered wrong if at an exam.

Comment: Well i wasnt sure if this is the reaction mechanism of a lewis base

Comment: How do you check if mechanism is correct/ realistic? Just adding up? Isn't it the less reactant the more likely it's gonna happen?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?